# How to reinstall OSX on a Macbook Air whose screen is broken, and OS has been erased?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

So I've had this Macbook Air for a while with a completely broken screen, and I wanted to give it to a friend who would work with it using a second screen. 
I plugged a second screen to start reformating, but of course once it rebooted, the image wouldn't go to the second screen.

So I'm stuck with a Macbook with a broken screen in the middle of the process of reformatting.
I'd like to reinstall OSX on it.

What do?

Comment: GIve it to your friend as is and let him/her deal with it.  The only other suggestion I have is to attach it to a second display, closing the lid on the laptop after starting it, and try Internet Recovery if you don't have a USB installer created. Have a look at, [OS X: About OS X Recovery](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314) and [How to Re-Install OS X with Internet Recovery on a Mac](http://osxdaily.com/2014/12/14/reinstall-os-x-mac-internet-recovery/)

Answer (score 2):

There are several options:

1. Plug in an external monitor and then you should be able to follow the install process.
2. Target disk mode, but as it's a MacBook Air this would be dependent on having a Thunderbolt port, that you can connect directly to another Thunderbolt port, or a Thunderbolt to Firewire adapter into an older Mac with Firewire.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, a sticky situation for sure!

Shot in the dark... Never tried this, so YMMV.

Try putting your broken Macbook in Target Disk Mode (https://support.apple.com/kb/PH10725?locale=en_US) and connect it up to the working Macbook. I'm reasonably certain Target Disk Mode is a firmware thing so you should be able to get it working without an OS. You'll know if that part works if the drive appears on the working Mac.

From there, you should be able to install an OS on the target disk from the working Macbook.

But, and this is a big one: For this to potentially not end badly, the working Macbook MUST be the exact same model with the same stats as your broken Macbook. Otherwise I suspect the wrong drivers will be delivered to the target drive by the installer.